# Web.Config, add information from the build user's environment

Tags: asp.net, build, web-config

Let's say I have a .NET web application that several developers are working on. This application sends out emails when they are interacting with it. I want emails to go to the person who deployed the application. So in web config we have:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SendEmailsTo" value="@EnvironmentUserEmail"/>
  </appSettings>
```

When they build and deploy the application, I want this to be replaced with the windows's users email address, so if John Smith deployes the application the web.config will contain.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SendEmailsTo" value="jsmith@email.com"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Any ideas how to pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

Use a prebuild event and call an executable (or some powershell script) to modify the config when you build for release.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) helps in solving your problem